# Vuetify 1.5 multiple dates datepicker shows blank dates with MM/DD/YYYY moment formatted date

Tags: datepicker, momentjs, vuetify.js, date-format

I have a requirement to use multiple dates in vuetify datepicker with 'MM/DD/YYYY' format with date selected as todays date. However when I use moment to choose current date and format it to 'MM/DD/YYYY' it is giving me an error of invalid time and displays blank datepicker.
Here's the codepen : https://codepen.io/raunaktwits/pen/rNLBgQN?editors=1010

```
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-date-picker
          v-model="dates"
          multiple
        ></v-date-picker>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-menu
          ref="menu"
          v-model="menu"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          :nudge-right="40"
          :return-value.sync="dates"
          lazy
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
          full-width
          min-width="290px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-combobox
              v-model="dates"
              multiple
              chips
              small-chips
              label="Multiple picker in menu"
              prepend-icon="event"
              readonly
              v-on="on"
            ></v-combobox>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker v-model="dates" multiple no-title scrollable>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(dates)">OK</v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dates: [moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'), moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')],
    menu: false
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**v-date-picker accepts ISO 8601 date strings (YYYY-MM-DD). For more information regarding ISO 8601 and other standards, visit the official ISO (International Organization for Standardization) International Standards page.**

As per the official documentation, you must choose dates in YYYY-MM-DD format

Also, duplicate dates might show an error.

```
dates: [moment().add(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'), moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')],
```

You can use this piece of code as your v-model

Also, if you need to show the date in your preferred format, display the date inside a text-field wrapped inside a v-menu

```
 <v-menu
      ref="menu1"
      v-model="menu1"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      max-width="290px"
      min-width="290px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="dateFormatted"
          label="Date"
          hint="MM/DD/YYYY format"
          persistent-hint
          prepend-icon="event"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title @input="menu1 = false"></v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
```

Here the **dateFormatted** can be used as per your convenience.

Have a look at this codepen.

[codepen.io/arjun3023/pen/BazapdM?editors=1010](http://%20codepen.io/arjun3023/pen/BazapdM?editors=1010%20Try%20this%20codepen)

Comment: I made changes to the codepen as per your suggestion but still cannot get it working...now the datepicker window itself is not getting displayed

Comment: @LearnerForever https://codepen.io/arjun3023/pen/BazapdM?editors=1010
Try this codepen